# Make a checkbox unique in a table row

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, checkbox, laravelcollective

I have an isActive column where a checkbox is dynamically generated within a foreach loop using php within Laravel. The column is in a table with some rows and each row has it's own unique id. Columns(Name, Address, info, info, Active) I've done some research but can't seem to find a solution. I want to make the checkbox unique and somehow want to append the id to the checkbox so I can grab the onchange state of the checkbox with javascript, because later I'm going to pass that value to the database without pressing a submit button. Thanks in advance.

```
<label class="switch switch-3d switch-primary">
                    {!! Form::checkbox('is_active', old('is_active'), old('is_active'),
                    ['id' => 'is_active', "class"=>"form-control switch-input".($errors->has('is_active')?"
                    is-invalid":"")])
                    !!}
                    <span class="switch-label"></span>
                    <span class="switch-handle"></span>
</label>
```

Comment: Simply append the index of the row that is being generated to the checkbox  id so it is unique,, ie: is_active-0, is_active-1,is_active-2 etc

Comment: What do you mean by "unique"? Allowing to check only one of the cheboxes? If so use radio instead of checkbox: https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_type_radio.asp

Comment: What I really have is a checkbox styled as a toggle slider. But when I set to inactive I want to set that row inactive. Since checkbox is generated in a php foreach statement there's one checkbox with the same name. I'm trying to append the id but not working so far. Thanks.

Comment: You do not need to have unique id. Just look at the parent. Can you post output HTML?

Comment: I'm looping to output posts in a php foreach loop. I can do a single checkbox activate/deactivate for a post with an ajax call in edit mode. But once it's i looping it lists the post. What I'd like to do is deactivate/activate on the fly on the list of posts. Heres the code I have so far.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/eddiewzp/625c0pqx/3/

Comment: Not sure if I mentioned. I'm just hitting a laravel route to do the update to the database. Thanks.